# Keep stroke-dasharray consistent when path length is changing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a path that is being drawn by the user, with D3.js.

I would like to have a dasharray defined on my user drawn path, however, as it changes its shape and length, the dash behaves inconsistently and the gaps are moving and becoming smaller.

Here is a codepen:

https://codepen.io/Richacinas/pen/YjXpBE

Feel free to fork.. the function that is drawing the user path is this one:

```
DrawItGraph.prototype.draw = function() {
    ...

    var pos = this.d3.mouse(event.target)
    if (pos[1] > this.chartHeight) return

    var date = this.clamp(this.middleValue + 2629743, this.maxValue, this.convection.x.invert(pos[0]))
    var value = this.clamp(0, this.convection.y.domain()[1], this.convection.y.invert(pos[1]))

    this.userData.forEach(function (d) {
        if (Math.round(Math.abs(d.date - date) / 60000000) < 50) {
            d.value = value
            d.defined = true
        }
    })

    this.yourDataSel.at({d: this.line.defined(this.format('defined'))(this.userData)})

    if (this.d3.mean(this.userData, this.format('defined')) === 1) {
        this.graphCompleted = true
    }
}
```

I suspect that I have to dynamically change the stroke-dashoffset and/or stroke-dasharray depending on path length, however, I have no idea what would the proper formula...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is not the dash array or the dash offset.  Lets look at an example generated path:

```css
.your-line {
    stroke: #ffb531;
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 15;
}
```

```html
<svg width="600" viewBox="1000 0 800 440">
  <path class="your-line" d="M1031.9776744186047,214L1099.9652386780906,189L1170.1216156670746,188L1238.0148837209304,188L1308.1712607099143,153.00000000000006L1378.3276376988983,174.00000000000003L1446.1266095471235,163.00000000000006L1516.2829865361077,218.99999999999997L1584.1762545899633,201L1654.3326315789475,201L1724.4890085679315,114.99999999999994L1787.85605875153,195L1858.012435740514,195L1858.012435740514,195L1787.85605875153,195L1724.4890085679315,114.99999999999994L1654.3326315789475,201L1584.1762545899633,201L1516.2829865361077,218.99999999999997L1446.1266095471235,163.00000000000006L1378.3276376988983,174.00000000000003L1308.1712607099143,153.00000000000006L1238.0148837209304,188L1170.1216156670746,188L1099.9652386780906,189L1031.9776744186047,214Z"></path>
</svg>
```

If we pull out the first few coordinates and the last few, the problem should become obvious:

```
M 1031, 214
L 1099, 189
L 1170, 188
...
L 1170, 188
L 1099, 189
L 1031, 214
Z
```

Your problem is that you are not drawing a single line, you are drawing a path that travels to the left and then back again, over the same coordinates, to the start.

As the length of the path varies, the dash pattern is interfering with itself and making the dashes appear to grow and shrink.

You need to update your line drawing code to draw a path in one direction only. Not a closed shape.

Comment: Majestic. Thanks so much Paul, it is as clear as water now. I'll try to post here a fork of the codepen with the solution

Comment: I'm trying to fix the problem, but it is not so easy... For some reason, as you say, I'm creating a line with double length, going and coming back, but I don't know why.

Comment: I expect it is the graph type you are generating with d3. I am not a d3 user, so I can't offer any suggestions on what to do next. Sorry.